# Pytorch is installed but is not working on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, pytorch, ubuntu-18.04, torch, torchvision

I am trying to install Pytorch via pip on ubuntu 18.04.I have python 3.6 and my laptop is HP-Pavilion notebook 15

The installation seems to be right because i get the message:

> Installing collected packages: torch, torchvision Successfully
>   installed torch-1.3.1+cpu torchvision-0.4.2+cpu

i run the verification code and it is ok

```
  from __future__ import print_function

  import torch

  x = torch.rand(5, 3)

  print(x)
```

However, when i close the terminal or reboot and try to run he same code i get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "torch.py", line 2, in 
>       import torch
>
> AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'rand'

Comment: Do you use a Virtual Python Environment? Maybe you installed pytorch globally but run the environment or vice versa?

Comment: Yes, i used a Virtual Python Enviroment on the installation but i think the problem is that pytho is installed but i cannot use i library. I tried with keras also but it's the same problem. Maybe is something wrong with the paths?

Comment: can you show us the output of `which python` and `which pip` before and after you switch terminals ?

Answer (score 1):

How are you executing the python script? Which python are you using? Maybe you installed the package in a different python version?

Try to set alias to the python you want to use:

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.6
```

Then pip install the package with that python alias you will always be using.

```
python pip install <package name>
```

Python now will install the package in the python files with the alias **python - heading to files: /usr/local/bin/python3.6**

Let me know if the error still occurs!

Comment: I am using python 3.6.6 and i try to execute the script from the command line like python3 example.py. The problem is that i tried to use Keras also and i have the same problem... any idea because i am a new user on ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Install pytorch using pip through the below command:

```
pip3 install torch==1.3.1+cpu torchvision==0.4.2+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

for any reference go through the [official website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) of pytorch.

Answer (score 0):

Change your file .py to another name, you named torch.py when you import torch it will call ur torch.py