# keep getting python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am working on a raspberry pi python project and every time I import a package I get the same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ''`. for example I am trying to add the ambient_api package

I followed the steps in their set up:

```
pip install ambient_api
```

Added the imports at the top of my file:

```
from ambient_api.ambientapi import AmbientAPI
api = AmbientAPI()
```

but I am getting the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ambient_api'
```

This is happening with all the imports I am trying to add and I cant figure out what I am missing.

when I was looking on google I came across `__init__.py` might be a solution but I am not sure how this works?

edit:

```
here is what was output when I installed:
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: ambient_api in /home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from ambient_api) (2.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from ambient_api) (1.24.1)
```

version in my terminal:
pi@raspberrypi:~/Raspberry-Pi-Greenhouse $ python --version
Python 2.7.16

but it looks like the version in the shell in the ide when I run the program is saying:
Python 3.7.3 (/usr/bin/python3)

Comment: With which python version are you installing the package? Working with the same python where you execute scripts with?

Comment: What is the file name for your script?

Comment: @JaFizz I am using pyhton 2.7.16

Comment: @cricket_007 the name of my script is greenhouse.py

Comment: do you have more than one version of python installed? I would also check to see if that module works with Python 2.7

Comment: Could you show us some screenshots when installing and executing, we then maybe can see the python versions you are using

Comment: @JaFizz just added more information to the post

Comment: @griffin_cosgrove it looks like there are two different versions my teminal says 2.7 but the shell when I run the program in the ide says 3.7.3

Comment: Does [this answer I wrote once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59358342/12488560) solve your question?

Comment: @JaFizz yes it does. It looks like this package works when I use python 2.7. Thanks!

Comment: Note: Python2 is end of life. Use Python3 to install and run your code

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @JaFizz in [Pytorch is installed but do not working ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59358141/pytorch-is-installed-but-do-not-working-ubuntu-18-04/59358342#59358342) it solved by giving an alias and installing correctly to desired python version (there were two pythons installed on the same machine)

First it was necessary to specify the location of the python, example:

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.6
```

Then install it:

```
python pip install <package name>
```